# Unit Testing - Theorem

Tags: java, unit-testing, theory

So, I've seen a video about TDD, where the presenter said, that you should unit test only the part of the class, what is give something out for the external world. He mentioned this is good, since this approach makes sure the class is keeping the "contract", so it's delivery its duty, but you are free to refactor the logic behind it.

I'm a bit confused here guys,because I learned that unit test should NOT depend from the outter world. Okay, I understand this is not a dependency, but why not testing the inside logic?
Any idea? Please feel free to add as an answer!

Comment: I think the phrase you are looking for is [*black-box testing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing).

Comment: Why SHOULD you test the internal logic? If a user expects f(a) returns b, why does it matter how f(a) does the work? The internal functionality is automatically tested by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly...  you test what is *outputting* to the "outer world," not *inputting* from the outer world.

The idea is, the more you test the internal steps your code takes to output the right result, the more your unit tests will unintentionally break when the implementation changes *even* though the final result is exactly correct. You only want unit tests complaining when the final result is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

So basically any internal logic in a class has to be exposed via some methods that can be accessed from out of the class. This way you're testing your internal logic, but you don't access it directly.